# MySQL state "closing tables" taking double the time of process

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a delete query that is taking a long time. When I check in `processlist` that status is showing as "*closing tables*". It is taking a long time to close tables.

*Example:*
I run a query and the total time is *1:42* seconds and in that *80-90* seconds are for closing table.

This is happening for all queries like `load data` , `select` and `insert`.

Below is *my.cnf* settings:

```
key_buffer_size = 2G
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 10M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
join_buffer_size = 2M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M

#tmp_table_size = 100M
#max_heap_table_size = 64M
#max_allowed_packet = 64M

table_cache=1024
```

My meminfo

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7862       6686       1175          0         11       4091
-/+ buffers/cache:       2583       5278
Swap:        15998         18      15980
```

Please tell me what kind of changes I need to do in *my.cnf* file?

Comment: _As a side note:_ try to avoid posting duplicate questions on the _StackExchange_ network. As far as I can see you posted the same question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/mysql-closing-tables-taking-double-the-time-of-process).

Answer (score 2):

**closing tables**

The thread is flushing the changed table data to disk and closing the used tables. This should be a fast operation. If not, you should verify that you do not have a full disk and that the disk is not in very heavy use.

You can look at [General MySql Thread States](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html) for additional details.

Hope this help!

Comment: This answer is [copied from this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21461/78772) - you could at least have referenced it.

Comment: @sankar-suda You can also try to run a trial of [Monyog] (https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) and check if it gives some insight. When I can figure something out usually some tools help you out.

Comment: Seeing the same issue on every mariadb start, disk is nearly empty and barely used. server is simply extremely slow on every start and for 30 minutes or more. This is very problematic on a galera cluster when one server is restarted it slows down the whole cluster for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following variables in my.cnf to avoid opening and closing of tables:

```
table_open_cache = 10000
table_definition_cache = 10000
```

have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache

and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-cache.html

Comment: I'm running mariadb seeing the same issue.
I doubt it'll do anything as I have table_open_cache=13869 and I see close_tables running for several seconds. But it happens on server start, and after half an hour or so it stops happening!?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of these two variables which are also important to improve mysql performance in this case.

**query_cache_size**: - Query Cache is flushed on every insert, this will hinder MySQL performance as it increases the overhead. Check if the value is too high and is in Megabytes.

**Innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit**: - You can set it to 0(log file is flushed to disk every second), 1(log file is flushed to disk for every commit) and 2(log file is flushed for every short interval in seconds).